# How do I load and view a PDF file in my app?

Tags: android, pdf, viewer, pdf-viewer, pdfrenderer

I've tried…

1. webview + google docs viewer
2. PdfRenderer

…but each of them has an issue:

1. is stable but can't change landscape mode. and can't choose initial page.
2. can choose initial page, and landscape mode, but it's very slow. and low resolution.

Does anyone know of any better options?

Comment: Currently, viewing pdf files in app have limitations as said, try passing an intent and opening them with pdf reader or anyother installed apps in your device. Will that work?

Comment: nope.. it should be open with in app.

Answer (score 1):

> it should be open with in app

Frequently, that is not what the user wants.

Beyond that, quoting [myself](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html):

> The PDF renderer that Mozilla uses for Firefox is
>   [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). This works with
>   Android's `WebView`, but only the modern incarnation of `WebView`
>   (i.e., Android 4.4+). It will also add ~2MB to your APK file, in
>   the form of a few MB of JavaScript that you need to package as
>   assets. But, it can handle a fairly wide range of PDF files.
>
> The PDF renderer that Google uses for Chromium is
>   [pdfium](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/). However, this
>   is C/C++ code, not JavaScript.
>   Bartosz Schiller's [`AndroidPdfViewer`](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) library
>   wraps Pdfium in a `View` that handles rendering and standard gestures (e.g.,
>   horizontal swipes to move between pages). This works well on older
>   Android versions (I tested through 4.1), but it adds about 5MB to
>   your APK *per CPU architecture*. By default, you get six architectures
>   and 30MB of overhead. With careful pruning of unnecessary CPU
>   support (see ya, MIPS) and ABI splits, you can minimize the per-APK
>   footprint, but you wind up with greater deployment complexity.